# What happens to a backup job, if it is scheduled and some prompt occurs?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup

For years we've backed up our system, using a tape drive on one of our Windows 2003 R2 servers.  And we've done this manually.  Whenever we do this, we'll put the tape into the drive, and get into the Windows Backup and Restore utility, bring up the saved backup job script, and run it.  It always prompts us twice; once to ask if we want to overwrite the data on the tape and to confirm the old save set.

That's nice and all, but I'd like to schedule this so that it happens automatically.  I've found on [enter link description here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5845132_schedule-windows-2003-backup-procedures.html) an article that describes how to schedule backups using the Windows Backup and Restore utility.  So that's great and all, but what about those prompts?  I certainly don't want this backup job waiting hours for some human to come along and click the OK button.

Comment: What software do you use for backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Windows 2003 Backup and Restore Utility - are there not options you can set when you create the backup schedule job that make sure it doesn't prompt?  Maybe you should try and find out?

[Here's how to schedule a backup.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759092.aspx)
Here's how to set [options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776659.aspx), and [advanced options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776659.aspx).